# Ignore Nulls in pandas map dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Dataframe looks like this :

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
A        M       X
B        F       Y
NaN      M       Y
A        nan     Y
```

I am trying to label encode with nulls as such. My result should look like:

```
COL1_    COL2_    COL3_
0        0       0
1        1       1
NaN      0       1
0        nan     1
```

The code i tried :

```
modified_l2 = {}
for val in list(df_obj.columns): 
    modified_l2[val] = {k: i for i,k in enumerate(df_obj[val].unique(),0)}

for cols in modified_l2.keys():
    df_obj[cols+'_']=df_obj[cols].map(modified_l2[cols],na_action='ignore')
```

Achieved Result :

[image]

Expected Result :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below code, I first use the `apply` function, than I drop the NaNs, then I convert it into a list then I use the `list.index` method for each value in the new list, and `list.index` gives the index of the first occurence of the value, after that convert it into the Series, and make the `index` the index of the series without NaNs, I am doing that since after I drop the NaNs it will turn from index 0, 1, 2, 3 to 0, 2, 3 or something like that, whereas the missing index will be NaN again, after that I add a underscore to each column, and I `join` it with the original dataframe:

```
print(df.join(df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(map(x.dropna().tolist().index, x.dropna()), index=x.dropna().index)).add_suffix('_')))
```

Output:

```
  COL1 COL2 COL3  COL1_  COL2_  COL3_
0    A    M    X    0.0    0.0      0
1    B    F    Y    1.0    1.0      1
2  NaN    M    Y    NaN    0.0      1
3    A  NaN    Y    0.0    NaN      1
```

Comment: Thanks @U10-Forward. I am trying to digest your code. It will be helpful if you can explain.

Comment: @Madan Sure i will, but before i do so, make you please up-vote and accept? (if it works)

Comment: If I have to replace the values in COL1,COL2,COL3 itself instead of creating new columns suffixed with _, how I have to change your code?

Comment: @Madan remove the `df.join` part

Answer (score 1):

Here best is use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) with `replace`:

```
df = df.join(df.apply(lambda x : pd.factorize(x)[0]).replace(-1, np.nan).add_suffix('_'))
print (df)
  COL1 COL2 COL3  COL1_  COL2_  COL3_
0    A    M    X    0.0    0.0      0
1    B    F    Y    1.0    1.0      1
2  NaN    M    Y    NaN    0.0      1
3    A  NaN    Y    0.0    NaN      1
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Learnt the purpose of factorize function today. Execution was fast with your solution.

Comment: @Madan - yes, unfortunately for missing values are returned -1 (because idea is always integers), so necessary replace.